# DataFrame - time since last positive and last negative value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"t": [1,2,3,4,5], 'val': [100, 5, -4, -9, 1], })
```

I need to calculate the following 2 columns, one for the time since the last positive value, and one for the time since the last negative value:

```
df['t_since_neg'] = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1]
df['t_since_pos'] =  [np.nan, 1, 1,2,3]
```

The column `t` stands for time. How do I do this? I know it would have something to do with `diff`, but I couldn't get it to work exactly.

Update (follow up question): how would I do this if I have an additional column ‘id’, and the calculations need to be done within each group separately, ie each group is independent of each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
m = df.val > 0

df['t_since_neg'] = df['t'] - df['t'].where(~m).ffill().shift()
df['t_since_pos'] = df['t'] - df['t'].where( m).ffill().shift()
```

---

```
   t  val  t_since_neg  t_since_pos
0  1  100          NaN          NaN
1  2    5          NaN          1.0
2  3   -4          NaN          1.0
3  4   -9          1.0          2.0
4  5    1          1.0          3.0
```

#### Explained

To calculate `t_since_pos`, first mask the values in time column where the corresponding `val` is negative, then forward fill and shift to propagate time corresponding to last positive value, finally subtract this from the original time column. The same approach can be used to calculate `t_since_neg`

```
>>>  df['t'].where(m)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    5.0
Name: t, dtype: float64

>>> .ffill().shift()
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
Name: t, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry, one follow up question: how would I do this if I have an additional column id, and the calculations need to be done within each group separately, ie each group is independent of each other? Thanks

Comment: In that case you need groupby. Please check: `df['t_since_neg'] = df['t'] - df['t'].where(~m).groupby('id').ffill().shift()
`

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that gives me KeyError id.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to obey id column. Perhaps I will post a separate question with more detailed test case, thanks.

Comment: Hey sorry, I was on mobile when I typed the message, i believe you should use `df['t_since_neg'] = df['t'] - df['t'].where(~m).groupby(df['id']).apply(lambda s: s.ffill().shift())`